# Use UI save button to update text field (swift)

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary, text

I'm attempting to update the information in the text fields so when the save button is pushed, it updates the information in the dictionary and reflects on the previous UITable. Here is the code for the student info swift page. I just can't seem to get it to update the information it stays the same.

```
protocol saveProtocol
{
func updateStudentInfo(firstName: String?)
}


class StudentInfoViewController: UIViewController {

var studentRecord = Dictionary<String, String>()
var delegate: saveProtocol?

@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailAddress: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var studentMajor: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var numberOfCredits: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = studentRecord["firstName"]! + " " + studentRecord["lastName"]!
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    firstName.text = studentRecord["firstName"]
    lastName.text = studentRecord["lastName"]
    emailAddress.text = studentRecord["email"]
    studentMajor.text = studentRecord["major"]
    numberOfCredits.text = studentRecord["numberOfCredits"]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func updateStudentInfo(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    delegate?.updateStudentInfo(studentRecord["firstName"])
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

}

Comment: I dont see where you assign value to `delegate` property. Show us please. Or you forgot and it is nil? Or did it set in previous view controller? Also, I dont see if you ever update your dictionary `studentRecord` with fresh info

Answer (score 0):

You should update the `studentRecords` dictionary in your `updateStudentInfo(sender:)` method. Since `Swift.String` is a value type, and not a reference type, changing `firstName.text` doesn't change what's in `studentRecords`

```
@IBAction func updateStudentInfo(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.studentRecord["firstName"] = firstName.text
    self.studentRecord["lastName"] = lastName.text
    // + all the other ones


    delegate?.updateStudentInfo(studentRecord["firstName"])
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two questions you should ask yourself: 1)where do I update the student info(where is your data source of your newly student info)? 2)who conform to the protocol and implement it?